# Javascript rerun the function until condition is false

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await

Via API, I would like to list out the whole users. Each time can only have maximum 100 items for each page. So that I need to get the next_page url to rerun the function - runPages to collect the list. So the condition is when the `next_page == null`, then will stop the function.

In my code, I can get the next_page url. However, it doesn't run further. Can someone figure out what is the problem?

```
const runPages = async (values) => {
  if (values.next_page != null) {
    for (const field of values.results) {
      row.appendChild(addCell(field.name));
      row.appendChild(addCell(field.email));
      tblbody.appendChild(row);
    }
    values = await checkPages(values.next_page); // get new values.data by url
    runPages(values);
  }
};
runPages(values);

const checkPages = async (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const getNewPageFromApi = async () => {
      const GetUrl = `${value}`;
      const Doorkey = { username: "XXX", password: "*****" };
      try {
        const response = await Axios.get(GetUrl, { auth: Doorkey });
        if (response.data.next_page != null) {
          resolve(response.data);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        reject("no more data");
      }
    };
    getNewPageFromApi();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for but since you're checking for `values.next_page != null` in the `runPages` function you can call the `resolve(response.data)` directly in the `Promise` inside `checkPages` function without checking for `response.data.next_page != null`.

Comment: Thanks @LHDi , yes after I removed the condition - both of them, now I can list out the whole data. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem @MoonFactory